# I can ping some host but not all from network on OpenVPN tun

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn

I have a network I want to connect to which is behind a firewall (iptables). On the same PC there's the OpenVPN server. It's directly connected to the Internet. I can connect to the server through OpenVPN.

I can ping some of the IPs but not all from the 10.0.0.0 network (inside network). I can ping VMs from a server but I can't ping the server. All of the machines are accesible locally.
I haven't got a clue what should I try next

Answer (score 1):

resolved the issue by adding to the firewall/gateway's iptable the following rule

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/16 -d <VPN_IP_address> --SNAT-to-source <gateway_IP>
```

gateway_IP being the IP of the gateway's internal interface

Comment: If you can ping some then the route exists. Why would that fix it?